# Como llenar 2 tablas con un formulario con laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, laravel-8

Trabajo con laravel 9

Tengo un formulario que carga 2 tablas de base de datos diferentes una tabla de **perfil** y otra tabla con la **dirección**, se guarda la información en el perfil pero no en la tabla de dirección no da ningún error.

Formulario con Laravel Collective

```html
    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'user.profile.store', "files"=>true]) !!}

    <!-- Nombre --tabla Perfil -------------------------------------------->
    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre', ['class' => 'block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700']) !!}
       {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>"mt-1 block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"]) !!} 

    </div> 


    <!-- Direccion -- tabla Direccion------------------------------------------>
    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
        {!! Form::label('direccion', 'Direccion', ['class' => 'block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700']) !!}
       {!! Form::textarea('direccion', null, ['class'=>"mt-1 block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"]) !!} 

    </div> 

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Model Perfil, relacion uno a uno

```php
    public function direccion()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Direccion::class);
        }
```

Model Direccion

```php
    public function perfil()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Perfil::class);
    }
```

Ahora el controlador
PerfilController

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
        {
           
            $profile=new Profile();

            
            $profile->name = $request->name;
            
            
             
            $profile->address()->direccion = $request->direccion;
            
           $profile->save(); 
     
           
        
        }
```

Comment: La relación `address()` de donde sale? ahi debería ir `direccion()` según como tenés configurados los modelos. Podrías mostrar tus migraciones o como están diseñadas las tablas?

Comment: La relacion  $profile->address()->direccion esta mal deberia de ser  $profile->direccion()->direccion